# Unable to remove NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, nvm

[image]

It says that node is installed in my `/home/raheel/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin/node`.
But it does not remove node with `apt-get remove node`.

I exactly don't remember how did i install it as i was following a tutorial.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`nvm` stores copies of node in a different place than the copy that your package manager installs. Also, it should be noted that the `node` package in Debian/Ubuntu is *not* node.js, but instead an amateur radio program (the actual package name is `nodejs`/`nodejs-legacy`).

So to remove `nvm`'s copy of node, you could do `nvm uninstall 0.10.40` to uninstall that particular version or you can do `nvm deactivate` to remove `nvm`'s node binaries from your `$PATH` entirely.